# Dig DNS root server doesn't give answer section

Tags: domain-name-system

I tried to get the name server for `com` TLD, here's the successful output when `dnscrypt-proxy` is enabled and the executed command is `dig com. ns`:
[dig success](https://bin.disroot.org/?bb097f4fb5ef9c2d#4vWaEdfu7gq9AWvm6w9uBYrwNHDCauXq13HZLFi9YB5q)

This is the result for `dig @a.root-servers.net com. ns`:
[dig no answer section](https://bin.disroot.org/?41a063b81598af84#3A4KAKDfpzmapVrrpJTo9s19FwQUKvG91N8FzeWoEX87)

This is the output using online dig interface and the command is  `dig NS +noadditional +noquestion +nocomments +nocmd +nostats com. @a.root-servers.net` [link](https://www.digwebinterface.com/?hostnames=com.&type=NS&showcommand=on&useresolver=8.8.4.4&ns=self&nameservers=a.root-servers.net)

```
;; Truncated, retrying in TCP mode.
com.            172800  IN  NS  e.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  b.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  j.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  m.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  i.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  f.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  a.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  g.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  h.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  l.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  k.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  c.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  d.gtld-servers.net.
```

The online dig interface tells me that it is possible for `a.root` to give me an answer, but I can't replicate it in my system.

Comment: "This is the result for dig @a.root-servers.net com. ns: dig no answer section" As expected. You get authority and additional sections. The link you are giving after is using a recursive nameserver, which will indeed reply with an ANSWER section. You are mixing authoritative and recursive roles and usages. PS: `+noall +ans` might be simpler/shorter than a long list of `+noX` but YMMV

Answer (score 0):

Based on the unexpected results that you showed, I get the impression that you are running `dig` in an environment where you do not have a "clean" network path that allows you to send DNS queries wherever you like; something intercepts and handles the queries.

Your `dig` output (quoted below) leads me to the above conclusion based on these findings:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.18.1-1-Debian <<>> @a.root-servers.net com. ns
; (2 servers found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 50284
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;com.                           IN      NS

;; Query time: 12 msec
;; SERVER: 2001:503:ba3e::2:30#53(a.root-servers.net) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Wed Jun 15 18:15:11 WIB 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 32
```

1. As you were getting at in your question, one would expected to see the `com` delegation `NS` records in the `AUTHORITY` section for this query directed at one of the root servers. Somehow this is not the case in your environment.
2. The root servers most definitely do not provide recursion services, but still you get a response with the `ra` (*Recursion Available*) flag set.
3. The query was clearly sent to address `2001:503:ba3e::2:30` (which is the IP address of `a.root-servers.net`), but the above behavior does not match what the root servers would do. Leaving me with the conclusion that in your network, something else intercepts and answers such a query.

You may want to experiment with queries such as:

`dig @a.root-servers.net version.bind CH TXT`

`dig @a.root-servers.net id.server CH TXT`

which *might* give some hint as to what it is that is actually answering.

Comment: [link1](https://bin.disroot.org/?695017f633a7442c#7HtgdHnyBtmFW585gu7paDCXQhhHNFXeZhWC9WHVakxH), [link2](https://bin.disroot.org/?40b7e0163bc90418#DjLit5rFh58kLYjon5mc9jY4w7wy1SsC7wLFKcFfKJFx). Still no answer and status is refused. What is the meaning of `id.server CH` and `version.bind CH`? I checked `dig`'s man page but found no such syntax. I assume `CH` means `chaosnet`? If yes, that's a different namespace. And yes, I use `dyncrypt` for bypassing censorship.

Comment: @In_Quisity Yes `CH` as in Chaosnet. In practice the `CH` namespace is mostly used for some metadata lookups such as these; where (if allowed, implemented, etc) `version.bind` returns the software version of the nameserver, and `id.server` the identifier of the nameserver, and some similar ones like that.

Comment: @In_Quisity I'm not familiar with `dyncrypt` specifically, but if it involves intercepting queries sent to any destination, that could be it, I suppose.